# B+TREE ORDER 3 splitting leaf node issue

Tags: indexing

I am looking B+Tree insertion.
Let say we have a B+Tree with n=3 and we are inserting 1,2,3 into the B+Tree.
After the insertion of 1,2,3, which results is correct?

Result 1:

```
  2
/   \
1    2|3
```

Result 2:

```
  3
 /  \
1|2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from my professor.
Result 2 is correct for text book database system concepts 6th edition.